# How can I change the hidden attribute on a windows folder using .NET?

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, system.io.fileinfo

How can I change an attribute on an existing folder?

I have to make this folder and all files existing in it visible.

C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\appdata

I found this code:

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(@"C:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Dane aplikacji");

attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.Hidden);


private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
    {
        return attributes & ~attributesToRemove;
    }
```

but it's not working :(

thanks !

Comment: What's not working about it? Is it throwing an exception (if so, what?)?

Comment: I realise this is not an answer, but why are you trying to un-hide a system folder?  If the user wants to see it, then they can do that via the Explorer menu.

Comment: Did you make an attempt to understand the code you found somewhere?

Comment: Not a proper answer, but a hint: is there anything special and/or magical about the variable `attributes`? Does assigning to it have any side effects?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are just updating the attributes variable but not actually updating the attributes for the file.

You need to use `File.SetAttributes('path', attributes)`